# Orthonormal base of eigenfunctions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A\colon H\to H$ be a compact symmetric operator with dense range in a Hilbert space. Show that the eigenfunctions form an orthonormal basis of $L^2([-L,L])$

*Hint: First consider the case of a point in the range. Consider the finite orthogonal projection onto the first n eigenfunctions. Use symmetry to infer convergence of the representation as $n\to\infty$. Then use that the range is dense.*

I have some problems to work with the given hint but here is what I did try so far:

> Consider the case of a point in the range

Let $A(x)=y$ in the range of A.

> Consider the finite orthogonal projection onto the first n eigenfunctions.

I think this means that we are assuming to have $n$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i, i=1,\ldots,n$ with $n$ eigenfunctions $v_i, i=1,\ldots,n$ and are looking for the subspace $V_n$ spanned by $v_i$.

Then, we consider the orthogonal Projection $P_{V_n}\colon H\to V_n$ 
$$
P_{V_n}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,v_i\rangle v_i, x\in H.~~(*)
$$

> Use symmetry to infer convergence of the representation as $n\to\infty$.

No idea.

> Then use that the range is dense.

No idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a bounded selfadjoint operator, then $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(Ax,x)|$. Now assume that $A$ is compact. Then the eigenvalues have finite multiplicity, and they tend to $0$ as a sequence, whether or not they are listed accordingly to multiplicity. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\cdots$ be the distinct eigenvalues listed so that
$$
     |\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_2| \ge |\lambda_3| \ge \cdots \ge |\lambda_n|\ge \cdots > 0.
$$
Then $|\lambda_n|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and 
$|\lambda_n| \ne 0$ for all $n$ because the range $\mathcal{R}(A)$ is dense, and because $A=A^*$ gives
$$
            \mathcal{N}(A)=\mathcal{R}(A^*)^{\perp}=\mathcal{R}(A)^{\perp} = \{0\}.
$$
Let $P_k$ be the orthogonal projection onto the eigenspace with eigenvalue $\lambda_k \ne 0$. Then
$$
       AP_k = \lambda_k P_k = (\lambda_k P_k)^* = (AP_k)^* = P_k A.
$$
The operator
$$
        A_n = A - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_k P_k = A(I-\sum_{k=1}^{n}P_k) = (I-\sum_{k=1}^{n}P_k)A
$$
is selfadjoint.

To see that the non-zero eigenvalues of $A_n$ are $\lambda_{n+1},\lambda_{n+2},\cdots$, suppose that $A_nx=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda\ne 0$ and $x\ne 0$. Then $x=\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-\sum_{k=1}^{n}P_k)Ax$ implies that $(I-\sum_{k=1}^{n}P_k)x=x$ and, hence,
$$
     Ax = A(I-\sum_{k=1}^{n}P_k)x = A_n x = \lambda x.
$$
The eigenvalue $\lambda$ cannot be $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ because $P_k x=0$ for $k=1,2,\cdots,n$. Therefore, the non-zero eigenvalues of $A_n$ are $\lambda_{n+1},\lambda_{n+2},\lambda_{n+3},\cdots$. The operator $A_n$ selfadjoint, and $A_n$ is compact because $A$ is compact. Hence,
$$
              \|A_n\|=|\lambda_{n+1}|,
$$
because $\lambda_{n+1}$ is the largest magnitude eigenvalue of $A_n$. Therefore $\|A_n\|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, which gives
$$
              \left\|A-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_k P_k\right\|\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow \infty.
$$
Because the range of $A$ is dense, and because $Ax=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_kP_k$ converges to $Ax$, then it follows that the linear subspace spanned by the eigenvectors of $A$ is dense in $H$, which implies that the set of eigenvectors of $A$ is a complete orthornomal basis of $H$.

Comment: @Rhjg : You know the largest magnitude of eigenvalue for $A-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_k P_k$, which coincides with the norm of this selfadjoint compact operator.

Comment: @Rhjg : The difference is $0$ on $\mathcal{R}(P_1+P_2+\cdots+P_n)$ and is $A$ on the orthogonal complement of this range.

Comment: @Rhjg : Compact implies bounded. Bounded and symmetric imply selfadjoint.

Comment: @Rhjg : They're good questions.

Comment: @Rhjg : Eigenvectors of $A_n$ with non-zero eigenvalues are eigenvectors of $A$, and the first eigenvalues are excluded by construction.

Comment: @Rhjg : You have $A= \sum_k \lambda_k P_k + A_n$ and $\|A_n\|\rightarrow 0$ by construction because $A_n$ is compact, selfadjoint, and the eigenvalues of $A_n$ exclude the largest eigenvalues. That's how you show $A=\sum_k \lambda_k P_k$.

Comment: @Rhjg : I rewritten that part to make all the details very clear. Have a look at the solution now.

Comment: @Rhjg : If you have a selfadjoint matrix, you also get an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. Actually, that's a special case of the spectral theorem for selfadjoint compact operators on a Hilbert space. Don't forget: for this case, or for matrices, you must find a basis of the null space of the selfadjoint operator if that is non-trivial.

Comment: @Rhjg : Nothing special about $L^2$ is needed. You have a Hilbert space, and a compact selfadjoint operator.

Comment: The range of A is dense, and $Ax=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k P_k(x)$. Why does this imply that the linear span of the Basis is dense?

Comment: @Rhjg : Everything in the range of $A$ can be written as a sum of eigenfunctions. So the linear span of the eigenfunctions is dense. Because the closed linear span of this orthonormal set is everything, then the orthonormal eigenfunctions form a basis.

Comment: Another question is what are the eigenfunctions resp. why is it called eigenfunctions since I thought the e_k form the basis and I would call them eigenvectors not eigenfunctions.

Comment: @Rhjg : $P_k$ is the projection onto the space of all eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. This is a finite-dimensional space for every $k$. If $\{ e_{k,1},\cdots,e_{k,n_k} \}$ is an orthonormal basis of the range of $P_k$, then $P_k x = \sum_{n=1}^{n_k} \langle x,e_{k,n_k}\rangle e_{k,n_k}$ and $AP_k x = \lambda_k P_k x$. I don't have time to chat. So keep the comments to a minimum or erase old ones.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Hilbert-Schmidt Theorem. The proof uses Fredholm Alternative and results pertaining to the spectrum of a compact operator on a Hilbert space. First by the compactness of $A$ you get that it has at most countably many distint eigenvalues, and by the Fredholm Alternative all eigenspaces (associated to nonzero eigenvalues) are finite-dimensional. Symmetry of $A$ provides that they are orthogonal too.

By taking the direct sum of distinct eigenspaces one obtains a subspace of $L^2$, which turns out to be dense (If $\{\lambda_n\}_n$ is the sequence of eigenvalues of $A$, then $\left(\oplus_{n} \ker(A-\lambda_n I)\right)^\perp\subseteq \ker(A)$). Finally one takes bases (consisting of finitely many vectors) of each distinct eigenspace. The union of these bases is guaranteed to be an orthogonal basis of $L^2$.

Comment: By the symmetry you can show that eigenspaces corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal. Then you can refer to the Bessel's Inequality. I believe even though the main idea is the same your construction is somewhat different. In the sketch I provide I worry about the bases of the eigenspaces themselves at the very end.

Comment: Denseness of the direct sum means that the inductive process of adding eigenspaces to each other indeed exhausts the whole space. Observe that $L^2$ is separable.

Comment: @Rhjg : The dense range of $A$ means the eigenvectors corresponding to non-zero eigenvectors must span a subspace that dense.